# Menu Font Size Not the Same

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar

A friend of mine has recently updated my website for me & unfortunately he is not available, the menu looked ok on every other page but on forum page the font size is smaller as compared to other pages.

Here is the link to the particular problem.
http://www.homemadetools.net/forum/

Can you guys please let me know what exactly is wrong so I could update the website accordingly.

Comment: Which menu are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `css.php` stylesheet added on the forum page which has this CSS declaration on line 1275:

```
body {
    color: #3E3E3E;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.23;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 650px;
    width: 970px;
}
```

The font-size here overrides the default font-size of 1em that is shown on other pages.
Note I used Firebug to determine which font-size CSS rules were actually being applied to these elements. It is a tool that you might want to familiarize yourself with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when I set that to 1em it appears bigger than that of other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in **styles.css** on line `269` and **css.php** on line `222`:

```
font-size: 13.75
```

should be:

```
font-size: 13.75px
```

That seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Both line 1275 and 1257 in css.php (its output, not the source) have `body font` or `body font-size` declarations respectively, that set the font size to 13px, which is then inherited to the menu. To fix it, you can set the `font` attribute at line 222 of the css.php (output) to

```
font:13.75px !important;
```

Which will then override any subsequent body declaration and fix your problem with the least hassle.

On further inspection it is just the lack of a 'px' denomination that prevents it from being chosen over the properly formatted body declarations. You can probably skip the `!important` flag then, as there is no actual inheritance problem. Just bad CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for all of your valuable help. I have done it with all of your help. changed the font-size:16px & then on that page font-family was Tahoma & not Arial, changed that & Boom. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

let me clarify you only want the "MENUS" not the forum section font size to be the same with the other pages?

just check the font size declaration on the stylesheets attached to the forum page